# google tests C++

Tags: c++, юнит-тесты, google-test

Решил попробовать гугл тесты в vs2017. При запуске тесты выскакивает такие ошибки :

error LNK2038: обнаружено несоответствие для "_MSC_VER": значение "1800" не соответствует значению "1900",

error LNK2038: обнаружено несоответствие для "RuntimeLibrary": значение "MTd_StaticDebug" не соответствует значению "MDd_DynamicDebug"

в мейне :

```
::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
```

сам тест :

```
TEST(RemoveTest, RemoveTestMiddle)
{
    EXPECT_EQ("I", remove("usually", "I usually"));
}
```

Comment: Есть подозрение, что google-test собран другим компилятором с другими настройками. Пересоберите его с те ми же настройками, что и проект.

Comment: @VTT как это сделать? я устанавливал gogle tests через управлением пакетами NuGet. и если в создании файла кликнуть кнопку тесты, то там не будет google tests, хотя по идее должны были

Comment: NuGet (в контексте C++) на практике вещь бесполезная. Собирайте google test самостоятельно из исходников. Тесты С++ не являются какими-то особыми файлами. Проект с тестами С++ также не является каким-то особым проектом (хотя шаблон для проекта google-test вроде есть из коробки, он бесполезен). Юнит тексты собираются в обычный exe из обычных исходников линкуя библиотеку gtest, вот и все.